# Help with Test Code coverage on APEX Callout

Tags: apex, api, rest, callout, code-coverage

attempting to develop a REST API connection to consume a webhook from Lesson.ly.  Have the data writing into our Org and now attempting to get code coverage around the class to deploy, but need help on the test classes.  Below I have referenced the primary class with the test classes for the a mock call out response and a test class.

This is for a REST call into a Force.com Site to catch the call from Lesson.ly's Webhook - http://www.lesson.ly/documentation/reporting-webhook-documentation/

**Primary Class:**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/LessonlyTD/')
global with sharing class LessonlyWebhook {

    public PageReference LessonlyJSON() {
        return null;
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static void postLesson() { 
        System.debug('Starter the postLesson');
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        String resBody = '';                  
        try {   
            System.debug('Original JSON: ' + req.requestBody.tostring());
            LessonlyJSON newLTD = LessonlyJSON.parse(req.requestbody.tostring());

            System.debug('NewLTD: ' + newLTD);

            Lesson_ly_Training_Data__c newLes = new Lesson_ly_Training_Data__c(
            ext_uid__c = newLTD.user.ext_uid,
            User_Name__c = newLTD.user.name,
            User_ID__c = newLTD.user.Id,
            Company_ID__c = newLTD.user.custom_fields.company_id,
            Email_Address__c = newLTD.user.email,
            Lesson_ID__c = newLTD.lesson.id,
            Lesson_Title__c = newLTD.lesson.title,
            Started_Date__c = newLTD.started_at,                           
            Completed_Date__c = newLTD.completed_at,        
            Assigned_Date__c = newLTD.assigned_at,
            Lesson_Score__c = newLTD.score,
            Report_Card_URL__c = newLTD.report_card_url
            );

            insert newLes;

            res.statuscode = 200;
            resBody = '{"success": true}';

            } catch (exception e){
                    System.debug('Error: ' + e.getMessage());
                    res.statuscode = 500;
                    resBody = '{"success": false}';    
            }  

            res.responseBody = Blob.valueof(resBody);                                               
    }}
```

**Mock Call out:**

```
@isTest
public with sharing class LessonlyWebhookCalloutTest {

    public static testMethod void testLessonlyWebhook() {

        PageReference pageRef = Page.lessonlytrainingdata;

        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Lesson_ly_Training_Data__c());
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);

        LessonlyWebhook controller = new LessonlyWebhook();

        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.user.ext_uid', '1');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.user.name', 'John Test');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.user.Id', '1234');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.user.custom_fields.company_id', '4242');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.user.email', 'testo@angieslist.com');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.lesson.id', '101');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.lesson.title', 'Lesson');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.started_at', '2015-04-28T14:36:22Z');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.assigned_at', '2015-04-28T14:26:22Z');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.completed_at', '2015-04-28T14:56:22Z');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.score', '0.87651');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('newLTD.report_card_url', 'http://sample.lesson.ly/assignments/100');

        LessonlyWebhook lesCallout = new LessonlyWebhook();                

        Test.stopTest();}}
```

**Test Controller:**

```
@isTest
public with sharing class LessonlyWebhookTest {

    public static testMethod void TestLessonlyWebhook(){
        PageReference pageRef = Page.lessonlytrainingdata;

        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TestLessonlyWebhookMockCallout());
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);
        String sEndpoint = '/services/apexrest/LessonlyTD'; 

        LessonlyWebhook controller = new LessonlyWebhook();

        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('ext_uid__c', '1234567890');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('User_Name__c', 'Sample Sampleson');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('User_ID__c', '1234');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Company_ID__c', '1234');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Email_Address__c', 'sample@company.co');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Lesson_ID__c', '1000');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Lesson_Title__c', 'A Sample Lesson');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Started_Date__c', '2015-04-28T14:36:22Z');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Completed_Date__c', '2015-04-28T14:36:24Z');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Assigned_Date__c', '2015-04-28T14:36:18Z');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Lesson_Score__c', '1');
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Report_Card_URL__c', 'http://sample.lesson.ly/assignments/100');
        Test.stopTest();  }}
```

Comment: Your code will probably be a lot more readable if you create some shorthand, namely `Map<String, String> params = System.currentPageReference().getParameters()`.

Comment: so the external system is REST posting to an APEX REST Service?  If so, then no callout mock is required to test the REST class; instead, you need to mock the JSON body

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you've written a WebServiceMock! Those are fantastic when you are calling out to an external resource FROM Salesforce, but it looks like you're actually trying to set up an endpoint that an external service can call.

The good news, this makes testing easier. Here's a great JeffD post on testing REST APIs: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2012/03/21/writing-unit-tests-for-v24-apex-rest-services/

Using his code as a start...

```
@isTest
private class Test_MemberRestSvc {

  static {
    // setup test data  
  }

  static testMethod void testDoGet() {

    RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
    RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

    // pass the req and resp objects to the method     
    req.requestURI = 'https://cs9.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v.9/member/me/results/today';  
    req.httpMethod = 'GET';

    LessonlyWebhook.postLesson(req,res);

    String jsonResults = res.responseBody.toString()
    //parse your return JSON and assert about it.    
  }

}
```